# How does Tomcat identify different connectors?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I am writing an upgrade script which would take Tomcat's `server.xml` and add an extra attribute to the each `Connector` node. This, however, needs to be done only for HTTP connectors but not others (e.g. AJP).

Looking at my Tomcat configuration, the only obvious different thing is the `Connector` `protocol` (e.g. `HTTP/1.1` or `AJP/1.3`), but [looking](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) at the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/ajp.html) I can see that there are different **default** values for the `protocol` attribute - for both AJP and HTTP connectors. This must mean that if you omit the `protocol`, Tomcat will somehow figure it out, based on the type of the `Connector`.

So how do I identify which connectors are HTTP? How does Tomcat do it?

Comment: i think if you dont mention the protocol, it is assumed to be http.

Comment: In this case, it goes against the documentation (which might or might not be misleading).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this article will be of value to you:
http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_http_connectors.htm

To sum it up for you:

> 'The Java-based HTTP/1.1 Connector is the default connector configured
>   in Tomcat...'

However, i believe in newer versions of Tomcat (6+), it will try to locate the APR libraries that will ensure better performance and will try to default to the HTTPApr connector:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html

> 'Once the libraries are properly installed and available to Java (if
>   loading fails, the library path will be displayed), the Tomcat
>   connectors will automatically use APR'

Hope that helps.